# Why won't my macro run automatically in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is my first time attempting VBA in Word although I've used it quite a bit in Excel. What I am trying to do is automatically execute my code after opening my Word template document. Here is the code I've placed in my Word template Module:

```
Private Sub AutoOpen()


Dim myValue
myValue = InputBox(prompt:="What is the client name", Title:="InputBox", Default:="Type your client name here")


stringReplaced = stringReplaced + "<Replace>"

For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With myStoryRange.Find
        .Text = "<Replace>"
        .Replacement.Text = myValue
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Highlight = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next myStoryRange



End Sub
```

I am using Word 2010. My code runs like I want it to when I manually go in and click run. However, when I close out of my Word document and reopen nothing happens at all. I've Googled the problem trying to find out a solution (and have attempt different versions of AutoOpen), but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any ideas on why the AutoOpen doesn't execute automatically? 
Thanks!

Comment: This http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-automatically-execute-a-word-macro-when-you-create-open-or-close-a-document/ would suggest Document_Open() instead of AutoOpen()

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that as well and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your code in standard Module in your Template document. Next, change sub name from `AutoOpen()` into:

```
Sub AutoExec()
    '..... your code here .....
End Sub
```